# REST call to insert records in another sandbox through Apex code

Tags: rest, soap, salesforce, apex

I am looking for exact apex code to fetch records from current sandbox and insert it into another sandbox. I am fine with both REST or SOAP API, please share the apex code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can solve it using one of ETL-tools without writing REST services and Apex code. There are a lot of ETL-tools, which supports Salesforce, for instance [Talend open studio](https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio/), [DreamFactory Monarch](http://www.dreamfactory.com/force.com/monarch) or [Pentaho Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/).

More broad list of tools with descriptions you can find on [Awesome Salesforce page](https://github.com/mailtoharshit/awesome-salesforce#etl-tools).